# Add Border around text in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

So I am working on messenger like application with reactjs. I can't figure out how to surround each text message with a border (exactly like telegram/whatsapp ...). the main problem is that it should be proportioned to the text written.
This is the styling that I stared with :

```
.messages{
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    border:2px solid rgb(134, 133, 133);
    width:100px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    background:white;

}
```

I would appreciate any help or references.

Comment: try padding instead of margin, or put the message in a div with same height and width and border

Comment: In order to have a border around the text and not around the whole div container, you need you use 'span' to place the text.

Comment: why not post the entire component so we can provide a better answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use wrapper component on the text like a div and apply with to the wrapper component also for making it proportional with text width you should add width: fit-content to wrapper components and max-width;
so your component will be something like this:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <span className="message">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid rgb(134, 133, 133);
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: white;
  text-align: left;
  /* max-height: 100px; */
}
```